# Distinct values based on correlated MIN() and MAX() values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table called EVENTS and I need to write 4 scripts to generate 4 separate tables of distinct EVENT_ID values. Below is the first script and the other 3 will be of a similar logic. Can anyone help with this first script please so I can then hopefully use it as a template for the other 3 scripts. I am writing these scripts in SQL2005 which must be backwards compatible with SQL2000. I have removed any duplicates so there shouldn't be a need to involve the rank of the EVENT_ID in the logic.

> For each CARE_ID select the value of EVENT_ID which has an EVENT_TYPE
>   of CP and has a MAX(EVENT_DATE) which is <= the MIN(EVENT_DATE) where
>   the EVENT_TYPE is in ('B','CH','S', 'T')

```
    CARE_ID    EVENT_ID     EVENT_DATE  EVENT_TYPE
    3          194          01/10/2012  S
    3          228          07/07/2010  S
    3          104          12/05/2010  CH
    3          16           12/07/2010  B
    3          17           13/07/2010  B
    3          43           15/01/2010  P
    3          189          15/04/2010  S
    39         45           09/10/2009  T
    39         4            21/07/2009  P
    39         6            21/07/2009  CH
    78         28           08/07/2009  S
    78         706          08/12/2010  CP
    78         707          09/12/2010  CP
    78         9            28/07/2009  T
    78         11           28/07/2009  CH
    95         21           31/07/2009  CH
    95         21           31/07/2009  T
    107        1474         21/09/2012  S
    107        93           23/02/2010  CP
    107        59           29/10/2012  P
    107        58           29/12/2009  P
    151        186          19/03/2010  S
    151        49           21/03/2010  T
    152        69           26/08/2009  CH
    206        85           21/08/2009  CP
    206        84           28/07/2009  CP
    217        158          18/02/2010  S
    217        102          30/03/2010  CH
    218        159          12/03/2010  S
    227        1378         01/04/2011  CP
    355        19           13/07/2010  B
    355        20           13/07/2010  B
    355        239          13/07/2010  S
    355        56           16/07/2010  T
    355        111          16/07/2010  CH
    364        1136         18/02/2011  CP
    364        569          19/02/2011  S
    364        774          23/08/2012  CH
    364        1122         26/01/2011  CP
    367        247          01/07/2010  S
    367        151          21/06/2010  CP
    369        108          26/07/2010  P
    369        152          27/07/2010  CP
    369        109          28/07/2010  P
    369        117          28/07/2010  CH
    369        248          28/07/2010  S
    380        277          08/07/2011  T
    396        1573         06/06/2011  CP
    481        63           07/09/2010  T
    481        116          07/09/2010  P
    481        194          07/09/2010  CP
    481        289          07/09/2010  S
    502        200          13/08/2010  CP
    530        220          14/06/2010  CP
    535        222          05/07/2010  CP
    535        303          13/07/2010  S
    535        223          19/07/2010  CP
    535        224          26/07/2010  CP
    536        135          10/09/2010  CH
    536        225          23/08/2010  CP
    568        155          06/10/2010  P
    568        315          15/10/2010  S
    631        148          02/02/2010  CH
    631        74           15/01/2010  T
    631        256          15/12/2009  CP
    631        345          15/12/2009  S
    631        147          25/12/2009  CH
    632        259          18/09/2010  CP
    653        189          29/10/2010  P
    653        360          30/09/2010  S
    655        1570         06/06/2011  CP
    680        569          08/12/2010  CP
    680        1191         24/11/2011  S
    680        530          25/01/2011  S
    680        151          30/09/2010  P
    680        281          30/09/2010  CP
    680        480          30/11/2010  CP
    689        306          02/11/2010  CP
    689        158          06/10/2010  P
    689        372          06/10/2010  S
    689        2720         06/11/2012  CP
    689        2736         11/11/2012  CP
    689        2752         13/11/2012  CP
    689        2765         15/11/2012  CP
    689        2125         22/09/2011  CP
    689        2654         24/09/2012  CP
    689        1944         26/08/2011  CP
    689        307          26/10/2010  CP
    689        1947         27/08/2011  CP
    729        299          15/09/2010  CP
    811        413          27/10/2010  S
    834        622          01/01/2012  CH
    834        1233         06/01/2012  S
    834        624          15/01/2012  CH
    834        625          23/01/2012  CH
    834        627          23/01/2012  CH
    838        629          02/01/2012  CH
    838        630          20/01/2012  CH
    838        632          27/01/2012  CH
    846        416          05/10/2010  S
    849        195          03/11/2010  P
    849        336          21/02/2011  CP
    923        441          26/07/2010  S
    963        371          29/10/2010  CP
    981        624          23/03/2011  S
    984        384          13/11/2010  CP
    984        392          18/11/2010  CP
```

Comment: Could you post what you expect the results to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried using a `HAVING` clause?  Maybe I've messed something up, but your test data only seems to have one such entry, namely for the `S` case, as follows:

```
SELECT  e.[CARE_ID], e.[EVENT_ID]
FROM    dbo.EVENTS e
WHERE   e.[EVENT_TYPE] = 'CP'
GROUP BY e.[CARE_ID], e.[EVENT_ID]
HAVING  MAX( e.[EVENT_DATE] ) <= ( SELECT  MIN( [EVENT_DATE] )
                                   FROM    [EVENTS]
                                   WHERE   [EVENT_ID] = e.[EVENT_ID]
                                       AND [EVENT_TYPE] = 'S' );
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edf8e/6) to help sort you out!

**Edit**: The original fiddle is looking for the maximum date of the `EVENT_ID`, when we're supposed to be looking for the maximum date of the `CARE_ID`.  I think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edf8e/12) will get you on the right track!

```
SELECT  e.[CARE_ID], e.[EVENT_ID]
FROM    dbo.EVENTS e
WHERE   e.[EVENT_TYPE] = 'CP'
GROUP BY e.[CARE_ID], e.[EVENT_ID]
HAVING  MAX( e.[EVENT_DATE] ) <= ( SELECT  MIN( [EVENT_DATE] )
                                   FROM    [EVENTS]
                                   WHERE   [CARE_ID] = e.[CARE_ID]
                                       AND [EVENT_TYPE] = 'S' );
```

**Edit 3**: [Now with proper `DATETIME`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76e3a/1)!

**Edit 4**: Distinct `EVENT_ID`!

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.[EVENT_ID]
FROM dbo.EVENTS e
WHERE e.[EVENT_TYPE] = 'CP'
GROUP BY e.[CARE_ID], e.[EVENT_ID]
HAVING MAX( e.[EVENT_DATE] ) <= ( SELECT MIN( [EVENT_DATE] )
                                 FROM dbo.[EVENTS]
                                 WHERE [CARE_ID] = e.[CARE_ID]
                                     AND [EVENT_TYPE] = 'S' );
```

Comment: Not sure this works because I expected to see EVENT_ID 93 in the list for CARE_ID 107 because it meets the conditions but it isn't there?

Comment: I don't see an EVENT_ID of 93 with an EVENT_TYPE of anything except 'CP' - that doesn't seem to be in the requirements as I understand them, as there is no record with a 'B','CH','S', 'T'.  You can wrap the condition in an ISNULL if you need to, but you'll probably get further providing some sample output... oh I get it.  See my edit!

Comment: CARE_ID 107 has a MAX(EVENT_DATE) of 23/02/2010 where the EVENT_TYPE of 'CP' - this is EVENT_ID 93. This MAX(EVENT_DATE) is before the MIN(EVENT_DATE) of 21/09/2012 from the group of events which have a EVENT_TYPE IN  ('B','CH','S', 'T') - this would be EVENT_ID 1474. Hope this clarifies and thank you for your input.

Comment: I had to modify the SQL Fiddle to use DATETIME to get this to work ( somewhat obviously, I'm new to SQL Fiddle ).  The `VARCHAR` date columns were not being `MIN` or `MAX`'d correctly.

Comment: Getting closer. This script doesn't return just the one EVENT_ID value, it returns multiples. An example is CARE_ID 364. The script returns the two values of EVENT_ID (1122,1136) which have EVENT_DATE values which are before the earliest instance where EVENT_TYPE = 'S'. I think I got around this by changing e.[EVENT_ID] to MAX(e.[EVENT_ID]) and removing e.[EVENT_ID] from the GROUP BY clause. A manual looksee seems to indicate it works. What do you think?

Comment: Maybe, but doesn't that cause you to lose the 1122 `EVENT_ID`?  You probably want to keep the `GROUP BY` as-is and do a `DISTINCT` instead.  Edit 4, incoming!

Answer (score 1):

This translate quite directly into SQL using window functions:

```
select care_id, event_id
from (select e.*,
             max(case when event_type = 'CP' then event_date end) over (partition by care_id) as MaxED_CP,
             min(case when event_type = ('B','CH','S', 'T') then event_date end) over (partition by care_id) as MinED_others,
      from events e
     ) e
where event_type = 'CP' and
      MaxED_CP <= MinED_others and
      event_date = MaxED_CP;
```

These functions calculate the `max()` and `min()` values on every row.  The outer query just selects the appropriate rows.

Note that if no such event exists for a given `care_id` then the `care_id` is not in the output.

This is not backwards compatible with SQL Server 2000.  If it works, then you can replace the window functions with subqueries.

Comment: This script returns a syntax error because aggregates have been used in the select statement and the columns represented by the * in the subquery are not in a GROUP BY clause

Comment: *‘The window functions’*? Is this using window functions?

Comment: @AndriyM . . . They were in my mind; now I've fixed it so they are in the answer too.  Thank you!

Comment: @PaulStevens . . . Try now (in SQL Server 2005) to see if it works.